# Page navigation to library in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I create a class library portable for universal app in visual studio 2013

i add new xaml file,rename it to page1.xaml and put some xml control in it.

after compiled the project, i added this library to my windows phone 8.1 project

now i want to navigate to page1.xmal in my library and load the page. how can i do it?

i try this code and an exception occurred

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("/mylibrary/page1.xaml"));
```

An exception of type 'System.UriFormatException' occurred in SYSTEM.NI.DLL but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `NavigateTo` method, using the page's type as parameter:

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(page1));
```

See [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh757631.aspx) for details about page navigation!

Comment: i try Frame.Navigate(Typeof(mylibrary.page1)); but nothing happend

Comment: Where do you call that function?

Comment: thanks for your comment,i fix it,i had problem in Page1 class

Comment: after Page1 load i want get result back to my app.do you know how to do that ?

Comment: Use the 2nd parameter of the Navigate() function to pass information